# Phalcon routing correctly pattern

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

Help with routing settings, there is the following request template with frontend: `/books/([0-9]+)/book-authors/([0-9]+)/images`

There is a controller located in namespace: `Shop\Controllers\Books\BookAuthors\ImagesController`

The controller has an indexAction method.

In routing.php I specify the following:

```php
$router = new Router(false);

$router->removeExtraSlashes(true);
$router->setDefaultNamespace('Shop\Controllers');
$router->setDefaultController('index');
$router->setDefaultAction('index');

$router->addGet('/books/([0-9]+)/book-authors/([0-9]+)/images', [
     'namespace' => 'Shop\Controllers\Books\BookAuthors',
     'bookId' => 1,
     'authorId' => 2,
     'controller' => 'images',
     'action' => 'index',
]);
return $router;
```

As a result, we get that the redirect always goes to the default controller. Please tell me how to fix...

I tried to debug and check why the template does not fit, but when I checked regex101 on the site, everything matches there and should work, but for some reason it does not work in phalcon.
Application return every time "not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route works fine, although you can try this for simplicity and clarity:

```
$router->addGet('/books/{bookId:[0-9]+}/book-authors/{authorId:[0-9]+}/images', 
 [
   'controller' => 'images',
   'action'     => 'index'
 ]
);
```

And in your `ImagesController` define `indexAction` as:

```
public function indexAction(int $bookId, int $authorId)
{
    echo "BookId: $bookId and AuthorId: $authorId";
}
```

For `/books/10/book-authors/22/images` the result should be:

```
BookId: 10 and AuthorId: 22
```

Comment: Thank you, I found a problem in the route configuration, the template "/:controller/:action/:params" was registered and because of it the routing took place earlier, lowered it to the very end and everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$router->addGet('/books/:int/book-authors/:int/images', [
    'namespace' => 'Shop\Controllers\Books\BookAuthors',
    'controller' => 'images',
    'action' => 'index',
    'bookId' => 1,
    'authorId' => 2,
]);
```

Note that I don't know if you can have multiple ":int" in the router definition and I have not tried this code.

If you can't have multiple ":int" in the line, you may need to restructure and move the bookId and authorId to the end and use :params.  Note that I also dropped the "images" controller name since you don't need that in the line.

```
$router->addGet('/books/book-authors/:params', [
    'namespace' => 'Shop\Controllers\Books\BookAuthors',
    'controller' => 'images',
    'action' => 'index',
    'params' => 1,
]);
```

Your URL would be something along the lines of "/books/book-authors/98/212" for bookID 98 and authorId 212.

Comment: Thanks, your idea with parameters helped me find the problem